# How get RichTextItem HTML content with big image?

Tags: javascript, java, html, lotus-notes, mime

To get HTML content of a RichTextItem, I use the following code :

```
Item vItem = aDocument.getFirstItem(aFieldName);
String vHTML = null;
if (null != vItem) 
{       
    if ((vItem.getType() == Item.RICHTEXT) || (vItem.getType() == Item.MIME_PART))
    {     
        DominoDocument vWrappedDocument = DominoDocument.wrap(
            aDocument.getParentDatabase().getFilePath(), aDocument, null, null, false, null, null);                 

        DominoRichTextItem vDominoRichTestItem = null;
        if (vItem.getType() == Item.RICHTEXT)
        {
            /**
             * create a DominoRichTextItem from the RichTextItem       
             */
            vDominoRichTestItem = new DominoRichTextItem(vWrappedDocument, (RichTextItem) vItem);       
        } 
        else 
        {         
            /**
             * create a DominoRichTextItem from the Rich Text item that contains MIME       
             */
            vDominoRichTestItem = new DominoRichTextItem(vWrappedDocument, aDocument.getMIMEEntity(aFieldName), aFieldName);      
        }   


        vWrappedDocument.setRichTextItem(aFieldName, vDominoRichTestItem);
        vHTML = vDominoRichTestItem.getHTML();
    }
    else
    {
        vHTML = vItem.getValueString();
    }
}
```

But if the RichTextItem contains a large image (eg a screen copy), the method getHTML return null.

I try browsing mime content, with this kind of code, but without success:

http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/6320b5c1150c7d3e85256c54004dd9a2?OpenDocument

How to do ?
Thank you

Comment: Have a look at an alternative call Domino DXL which you may be able to use to retrieve the MIME portion that you need if you are still stuck